# Working example of AWS API Gateway integration with SNS, including MessageAttributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns, openapi

I have a working API Gateway integration with SNS, including CloudWatch logging for the API Gateway (which took some figuring out). The last piece I need now is to get the SNS messages to include `MessageAttributes`. Hunting for a complete example in AWS documentation seems difficult/ if not impossible... Could someone please share a working example please?

Here is what I have so far:

```
  SfdcPlatformEventsApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    DependsOn:
      - SfdcPlatformEventsApiLogGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '${EnvironmentName}-${ApplicationName}-api'
      StageName: !Ref EnvironmentName
      AccessLogSetting:
        DestinationArn: !GetAtt SfdcPlatformEventsApiLogGroup.Arn
        # 'requestId' is useless... but it is required for AccessLogSetting
        Format: '{
                     "request_id": "$context.requestId",
                     "api_id": "$context.apiId",
                     "domain": "$context.domainPrefix"
                     "path": "$context.path",
                     "param": "$integration.request",
                     "http_method": "$context.httpMethod",
                     "source_ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp",
                     "user-agent": "$context.identity.userAgent",
                     "api_key": "$context.identity.apiKey",
                     "status": "$context.status",
                     "responseLatency": "$context.responseLatency",
                     "requestTime": "$context.requestTime",
                     "wafResponseCode": "$context.wafResponseCode",
                     "xrayTraceId": "$context.xrayTraceId",
                     "error_message": "$context.error.message",
                     "error.validationErrorString": "$context.error.validationErrorString"
                 }'
      MethodSettings:
        - DataTraceEnabled: true
          HttpMethod: '*'
          LoggingLevel: INFO
          ResourcePath: '/*'
          MetricsEnabled: true
      # enable xRay tracing
      TracingEnabled: true
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        info:
          title: !Sub '${EnvironmentName}-${ApplicationName}-api'
        paths:
          /{proxy+}:
            post:
              responses:
                '202':
                  description: 'Published'
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                type: aws
                httpMethod: POST
                uri: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sns:action/Publish'
                credentials: !GetAtt SfdcPlatformEventsApiRole.Arn
                parameters:
                  name: proxy
                  in: path
                  required: true
                  type: string
                requestParameters:
                  method.request.path.proxy: true
                  integration.request.querystring.Type: 'method.request.body.attributes.type'
                  integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes: 'method.request.body.attributes'
                  integration.request.querystring.Message: 'method.request.body'
                  integration.request.querystring.TopicArn: !Sub "'${SfdcPlatformEventsSnsQueue}'" #It looks funky here with the double and single quotes!! But it needs it!
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: 202
              security:
                - API_KEY: []
              x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source: HEADER
              x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
                ACCESS_DENIED:
                  statusCode: 403
                  responseTemplates:
                    application/json: !Ref AccessDeniedMsg
        securityDefinitions:
          API_KEY:
            type: 'apiKey'
            name: 'x-api-key'
            in: 'header'
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the correct syntax to pass in the MessageAttributes. Here is the working version API definition in its entirety. I hope this will save someone else the hassle of having to search through tons of AWS documentation.

```
SfdcPlatformEventsApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    DependsOn:
      - SfdcPlatformEventsApiLogGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '${EnvironmentName}-${ApplicationName}-api'
      StageName: !Ref EnvironmentName
      AccessLogSetting:
        DestinationArn: !GetAtt SfdcPlatformEventsApiLogGroup.Arn
        # 'requestId' is useless... but it is required for AccessLogSetting
        Format: '{
                     "request_id": "$context.requestId",
                     "api_id": "$context.apiId",
                     "domain": "$context.domainPrefix"
                     "path": "$context.path",
                     "param": "$integration.request",
                     "http_method": "$context.httpMethod",
                     "source_ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp",
                     "user-agent": "$context.identity.userAgent",
                     "api_key": "$context.identity.apiKey",
                     "status": "$context.status",
                     "responseLatency": "$context.responseLatency",
                     "requestTime": "$context.requestTime",
                     "wafResponseCode": "$context.wafResponseCode",
                     "xrayTraceId": "$context.xrayTraceId",
                     "error_message": "$context.error.message",
                     "error.validationErrorString": "$context.error.validationErrorString"
                 }'
      MethodSettings:
        - DataTraceEnabled: true
          HttpMethod: '*'
          LoggingLevel: INFO
          ResourcePath: '/*'
          MetricsEnabled: true
      # enable xRay tracing
      TracingEnabled: true
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        info:
          title: !Sub '${EnvironmentName}-${ApplicationName}-api'
        paths:
          /{proxy+}:
            post:
              responses:
                '202':
                  description: 'Published'
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                type: aws
                httpMethod: POST
                uri: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sns:action/Publish'
                credentials: !GetAtt SfdcPlatformEventsApiRole.Arn
                parameters:
                  name: proxy
                  in: path
                  required: true
                  type: string
                requestParameters:
                  method.request.path.proxy: true
                  integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes.entry.1.Name: "'sfdcObject'"
                  integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.StringValue: "method.request.body.sfdcObject" # The value must be top level inside body: 'method.request.body.attributes.sfdcObject' does not work
                  integration.request.querystring.MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.DataType: "'String'"
                  integration.request.querystring.Message: 'method.request.body'
                  integration.request.querystring.TopicArn: !Sub "'${SfdcPlatformEventsSnsQueue}'"
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: 202
              security:
                - API_KEY: []
              x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source: HEADER
              x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
                ACCESS_DENIED:
                  statusCode: 403
                  responseTemplates:
                    application/json: !Ref AccessDeniedMsg
        securityDefinitions:
          API_KEY:
            type: 'apiKey'
            name: 'x-api-key'
            in: 'header'
```